# Re-mount EBS vol on EC2 instance

Tags: linux, lvm, mdadm, mongodb

I am new to sysadmin.

I am trying to launch a EBS-backed EC2 instance.

I did the following based on mongodb docs:

```
sudo mdadm --verbose --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --chunk=256 --raid-devices=1 /dev/xvdh1
echo 'DEVICE /dev/xvdh1' | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm.conf
sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm.conf
sudo blockdev --setra 128 /dev/md0
sudo blockdev --setra 128 /dev/xvdh1
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/md0 bs=512 count=1
sudo pvcreate /dev/md0
sudo vgcreate vg0 /dev/md0
sudo lvcreate -l 90%vg -n data vg0
sudo mke2fs -t ext4 -F /dev/vg0/data
sudo mkdir /data
echo '/dev/vg0/data /data ext4 defaults,auto,noatime,noexec 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mount /data
```

Now I terminated EC2 instance and trying to re-mount the EBS-vols to newly launched instance.

What I was not sure:

- which of the above steps I need to do?
- Which of the above steps I can skip?
- Which of the above steps I SHOULD NOT DO at all ?(which can make things inconsistent)

On the new EC2 instace, I tried to execute the following cmd but then aborted due to warning.

I was not sure

```
sudo mdadm --verbose --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --chunk=256 --raid-devices=1 /dev/xvdh1
mdadm: layout defaults to n2
mdadm: layout defaults to n2
mdadm: /dev/xvdh1 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid10 devices=5 ctime=Fri Jul 26 18:01:23 2013
```

After going thru warning/errors while executing, I skipped following steps and re-mounted:

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/md0
sudo vgcreate vg0 /dev/md0
sudo lvcreate -l 90%vg -n data vg0
```

but all the data in EBS vol is lost.

If somebody could verify, that would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create a mirror from a single EBS volume, if you arent going to mirror it, you could have used it directly.

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/xvdh1
sudo vgcreate vg0 /dev/xvdh1
sudo lvcreate -l 90%vg -n data vg0
sudo mke2fs -t ext4 -F /dev/vg0/data
```

Then if you detach this volume and attach somewhere else.

```
sudo pvscan
```

will show the new partition.

```
sudo lvsan
```

Will show the logical volumes on this migrated partition.

```
sudo lvactive <volume name>
```

Will activate the volume so you can mount it.

```
sudo mkdir /data
sudo mount  /dev/vg0/data /data
```

If you want this to be mounted every time you boot, add it to the /etc/fstab